# Dealing with JSONish things in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm using PHP to consume a service that is not mine.  This service returns things that are almost, but not quite, entirely unlike JSON (hat tip, HGG).

i.e., in their simplest form, they look like this

```
{a: 8531329}
```

Running the above string through `json_decode` returns NULL

```
$foo = json_decode('{a: 8531329}');
```

The problem is that `a` isn't quoted.

```
$foo = json_decode('{"a": 8531329}');
```

Does PHP (either natively or via common packagist packages) offer me a way to parse this "valid-javascript-but-not-valid-json" string into a PHP array or stdClass?  Or will I be parsing this myself?  (my example above is a simple case -- actual strings are rather large)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON5 may be what you need: https://github.com/colinodell/json5

It deals with all things that object literals in JavaScript are allowed to have while JSON isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If we define the input string as `$i`:

```
$i='{a: 8531329}';
```

We can pre-process it to make it valid JSON with `preg_replace`:

```
json_decode(preg_replace('/\{([^:]*):/', '{"\1":', $i))
```

I would need to see a larger set of what needs to be corrected to provide a complete solution, of course.

Comment: Also: non-decimal numbers, trailing commas, single quotes, comments.

Comment: +1 because I do love me a regex -- that said I don't think this is the right solution for me, in this case.  Trying to one off a regular expression that covers all possible things this third party service might throw at me seems like it would be a long term solution.